# Performance lag for database replication

Tags: database-performance, mirroring, database-replication

My company is really sensitive about keeping up the performance on our core system. Our users also have a requirement to replicate or mirror all data to another location (in another location within city limits) in case a disaster happens. A software vendor came up with a proposal to implement **GoldenGate** system.

I'm having trouble believing the proposal saying it will have no impact on performance because it utilizes the log that is written during database write. They keep saying that reading the log will have no impact on the server performance. I know for sure writing the log does though.

Also doesn't data transfer from the source to the destination impact the performance of the source server? I'm a beginner at this. Does communication through sockets really have no impact on the source server?

Is there a better way to mirror data without sacrificing performance, **at all**?

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring data will have some impact, but that impact may already exit.  Writing the log files incurs a performance penalty to ensure database integrity and recoverability.

Hot backups populated from log files have been used for a long time.  There will be a small load to transfer the file to the remote site.  Depending on the log file size and count you might get some blocking under high load.  There will be latency on the updates.  This may be significant depending on when the and how the the log data is copied.  In case of disaster you will likely loose data from the latency period.

Comment: thanx for the insight bill. performance penalties are definitely things we must consider in order to achieve integrity and the ability to recover data.